# funcion javascript principiante

Tags: javascript, funciones

problema : Escribe una función llamada evaluate que reciba como parámetro un número retorne lo siguiente:
"Positivo" si el número es positivo.
"Negativo" si el número es negativo.
"cer0" "Cero" si el número es cero.
respuesta propuesta:

```js
function evaluate(number){
     number= 0;      
     if(number > 0){
         return 'Positivo'
     }else if(number < 0){
         return 'Negativo'
     }else{
         return 'Cero'
     }
     
}
evaluate();
```

no me sale, me sale error, ayuda por favor

Comment: Dices que te sale error. ¿Podrías aclarar cuál error te sale? Saludos

Answer (score 2):

En la segunda línea estás forzando que la variable `number` sea siempre igual a 0, por lo que independiente del valor que le entregues a la función se cumplirá que `number = 0` en todos los casos.

> **Solución:** Elimina la línea de código `number = 0` y entrega un número a la función al momento de llamarla, por ejemplo: `evaluate(5)`

Comment: Buena respuesta, puedes mejorarla agregando la función corregida y la llamada en un fragmento de código. +1

Comment: gracias maxrojas, me ha funcionado y lo he entendido!!

Answer (score 1):

En tu función luego de recibir el numero lo estas igualando a cero, todos lo resultados darán cero, yo lo haria asi:

```
function evaluate(number){
        estado=""
        if (number>0) {
            estado="positivo"
        } else if(number<0) {
            estado="negativo"
        }else if(number==0){
            estado="cero"
        }
        return estado
    }
    console.log(evaluate(-9))
```

Comment: gracias karlo ojeda, intente tu solucion y tambien ha funcionado

Answer (score 1):

```js
function evaluate(number){
           
     if(number > 0){
         console.log("El número es positivo");
     }
     else if(number < 0){
         console.log("El número es negativo");
     }
     else{
         console.log("El número es 0");
     }
     
}
evaluate(-1);
```

Yo lo que haría si no necesitas reutilizar esas variables y solo lo quieres mostrar por pantalla utilizaría console.log y no declaro variables. Cuando llames a la función ya pones tu el valor que quieras analizar.

Comment: gracias toperon!!

Answer (score 0):

La funcion esta esperando un parametro **evaluate(number)**

cuando la llamas no le estas pasando ese parametro, en este caso seria un valor numerico osea...

```js
function evaluate(number){
     number= 0;      
     if(number > 0){
         return 'Positivo'
     }else if(number < 0){
         return 'Negativo'
     }else{
         return 'Cero'
     }
     
}

evaluate(2);
```

como por pantalla no va a mostrar nada xq solo estas retornando un valor, te recomiendo mirar el resultado con un alert(evaluate(2)); o por consola con console.log(evaluate(2));

Comment: gracias, CSH Ktimporta!!